# Can this arraylist ever be equal to null?

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I just wanted to know if I need to place a check for null at Point A below. Will it ever be null at that point? Or will it only be empty/non-empty?

Thx in advance for any help!

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String sql ="SELECT * FROM XXXXX"; 

ps = getDBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
 //Add the row to myList using myList.add...
}

if (myList != null){ //POINT A
//Implement some logic
}

..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` is just a reference. It could in principle point to `null`, of course. In your example, however, you directly assign it to a `new ArrayList()` and nothing changes `myList` in between so, no, it can never be null

Comment: Thanks for confirming it!+1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you create it at the first line (`List myList = new ArrayList();`), it can't be null unless you explicitly assign null to it.

If you want it to be null you will have to do : `myList = null`

Also, when you create an object, the object can still be null is if the constructor throws an exception:

```
MyObject obj = null;
try {
      obj = new MyObject(); // If an exception is thrown, the assignment is not done
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // Do something
}

// Here obj is null if an exception has been thrown
```

But it's now the case in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You initialized `myList` with `myList = new ArrayList()` already so it won't be null ever again, unless you do something like `myList = null;`

Also, it can't be null if you call `myList.add` in the loop above it or you will get a `NullPointerException`. So if you check for null anywhere, it should be above the while-loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure it can never be nulled, declare it like this:

```
    final List myList = new ArrayList();
```

Either way, it can only be `null` if some code in this method (after the declaration) explicitly assigns a `null` to it.

Comment: Very nice answer and a good addition to the accepted answer by Miquel.